# Cloning failed using an ssh key for authentication

Tags: php, laravel

My PHP version is 8.1.and when I installed Laravel 9, I set this error in CMD.

[image: cmd]

What is this message and what I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: There is a link there in the output that will provide a token for access to public repos. Simply copy and paste that into your browser and then enter the token code back into your terminal. 

I would also suggest setting up SSH keys on your machine and then add them to your GitHub account as it will make things a whole lot easier for you in the future

Answer (score 1):

As it is written in your console, visit https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/authentication-for-private-packages.md#github-oauth for more info.

and then configure your token on GitHub https://github.com/settings/tokens
to be able to access that repository.

Answer (score -1):

You can also get this error if you run out of disk space.